# PowerShell 2 - Displaying Share Directory Where Everyone has Full Control

Tags: windows, powershell, command

**PowerShell Version:** 2 (I understand the risks)

The following command outputs all shares where the "everyone" user group has access:

```
$Found = @()
Get-WmiObject win32_logicalsharesecuritysetting |
    ForEach-Object {$Path = "\\localhost\\" + $_.Name; Get-Acl -Path $Path |
        Select-Object Path -ExpandProperty Access |
            ForEach-Object {If($_.IdentityReference -eq 'Everyone'){$Found += $_.Path}}}
            
Write-Host "Found: $($Found.Count)"
Write-Host "Share locations:"

$Found | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_.Replace('Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\localhost\','')}
```

Can the command above be enhanced to only display shares where the "everyone" user group has "full control" only?

If the radio button is not selected, don't display anything in the output, however, if that full control radio button is selected for the user group "everyone", display an output:

[image]

Comment: Its part of the ACL, so just add another condition to your `if` statement: `$_.IdentityReference -eq 'Everyone' -and $_.FileSystemRights -eq 'FullControl'`.

Comment: Hi Abraham, I've modified the if statement as you have suggested to: ForEach-Object {If($_.IdentityReference -eq 'Everyone' -and $_.FileSystemRights -eq 'FullControl'){$Found += $_.Path}}}    and it seems to be working perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear!(:

Answer (score 1):

so in my program i use this piece of code:

```
$Shares = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting
foreach($Share in $Shares) {
    foreach($perm in $Permissions.Descriptor.DACL) {
        if($Perm.Trustee.Name -eq "EveryOne" -and $Perm.AccessMask -eq "2032127" -and $Perm.AceType -eq 0) {
                    #EveryOneFullControl is true so do something
                } else {
                    #EveryOneFullControl is false so do something                 
                }
    }
}
```